# I have pr0blem with AsyncTask class in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have problem when the AsyncTack class run in background.Code is run prefectly but problem is when the AsyncTask run my app auto resume.
 Here is the code

**BackTask.java**

```
public class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

    Context context;

    public BackTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String method = strings[0];


        if (method.equals("register")) {

            String lang = strings[1];
            String lat = strings[2];
            Log.i("Check:", lang + " " + lat);
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://wishes4u.000webhostapp.com/API/signup.php");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("lang", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lang, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lat, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                return "Registration Success!";


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s.equals("Registration Success!")){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Registration Success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**Main_Activity.java**

```
  public void registerUser(View view) {

        regEmail = email.getText().toString();         
        regPassword = password.getText().toString();

        String method = "register";
        BackTask backTask = new BackTask(this);
        backTask.execute(method, regEmail, regPassword);
        finish();

    }
```

I'm run the app on the android 4.4.2 (kitkat).

I cannot know where is problem....

Comment: You need to explain what's going wrong better.  Is it crashing?  If so post the log.  Is it not working?  What isn't working, what did you expect and what is it doing instead?  Is it doing something odd?  Exactly what is that?

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, but you should be careful with that `finish()` call after the `executes()`. Your `backTask` can finish after the activity gets closed. This finish method basically tells Android that he can close your activity. Can you explain better what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @GabeSechan no app craching , working well but app minimize (resume) when the AsyncTask class run.

Comment: THe actiity is closing because you're calling finish.  If you don't want that, delete the call.

Comment: Remove that `finish()` after your execute. What is happening is that you task async code is being executed while android is closing your activity, if I understood your problem correctly. You should notify the activity inside your task, this could be done by making your activity implement a listener.

Comment: @KayanAlmeida Thank you very much problem with finish() I remove it and run again its works perfectly thanks again..

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you So much...

Comment: You're welcome @MuhammadKashif. If you want to close your activity after your task ends, you should do this inside your task, since it will be done in another thread (not the UI thread)! Good luck!